# ios5 - posting to facebook when facebook app is already on device

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I'm following the information provided in [facebook url](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/). Its working well and good if facebook app is not there on the device.
consider facebook app is not on device: i'm authorizing facebook and its opening safari. i authorize the app, comes back to ios app and it calls the delegate "fbDidLogin" in FBSessionDelegate. I'm saving the access token and expiration date as mentioned in above URL. Then later, I'm able to post it facebook. This works fine.
now, facebook app is available on the device and logged in also: when i call "authorize", it opens facebook app and authorizes the app, then comes back to the ios app. but its not calling "fbDidLogin" delegate method. how should I recognize or catch the access token and expiration date?
I'm writing the following code:

 facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:FB_APPID andDelegate:self];

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) 
{
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

NSArray* permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream",nil];
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) 
{
    [facebook authorize:permissions];
}



- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"IIRY_FACEBOOK"];        
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Can some one point me the mistake that I'm doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem is that the bundle ID mentioned in facebook app and my app's bundle Id are not same and so its not working.
[Look the URL to know more](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7257894/authentication-fails-with-facebook-app-installed-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you tap on authorize then it will open safari and if there is facebook app on device then it will open facebook app otherwise it will open facebook in safari. If you don't want to open the safari and facebook app then in facebook.m change this statement everywhere where it is calling to NO.

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```

Comment: But I still want to use default functionality without changing facebook code. But as per the facebook documentation, they didn't mention anything on how to handle this situation. pretty bad.